# Ice blocks melting outdoors

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, ice

I have a question, that is not related to anything academic.
We are planing a festival in winter, that will have some stage set up of ice blocks.
There will be several big rectangular prisims of ice, each composing of three ice blocks, that are put and melted on top of each other The whole thing will be 50x50x250cm (WxLxH). The ice is not pure on some points, there is another material, made of some plastic element. 
This whole thing will stay outddors, at -10 to 10 degrees with possible wind, sunshine and maybe rain! 
Is there a way to estimate how they will melt and if it is possibly dangerous to leave them there, bacause they might crash rather than melting nicely?
This is how far i got: https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/imarusic/proceedings/19/40.pdf

I would appreciate comments and further connections!
Thank you and have a nice warm day :)
Mehtap

Comment: We'd need details on the setting (materials, colors, position of the surroundings of the ice blocks - which makes this more of an engineering question) and anyway I'm afraid the variability of the possible weather conditions makes any prediction too uncertain.